# How to hide part of page from Google indexation?

Tags: html, search, indexing

I have page and I need to hide part of the page from indexation. How can I do it? I need to hide only part of the page, it's important detail. I don't know how I can do it; I've got one idea - move this part to other html file and add it using iframe to main page; iframe page I will block from indexation with meta tag. Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: You can't hide a part, only full pages.

Put this in robots.txt and put it in the root folder on your server

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /pathto/page.html
```

Another thing you could do is add `rel="nofollow"` on links directing to the full page you want to hide. [Info](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en)